# Python RegEx for all National Drug Codes (NDC 10 & 11) formats

Tags: python-3.x, regex, ndc

Goal: RegEx to fit many posible NDC 10 & 11 formats.

I've made a great start...
**NDC 10:**

```py
^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]$
```

e.g. `1234-1234-12`
[Reference](https://www.idmedicaid.com/Reference/NDC%20Format%20for%20Billing%20PAD.pdf)

---

However, I've since learnt there are other formats and 11 digits:

- 4-4-2
- 5-3-2
- 5-4-1
- 5-4-2 (11 digits)

**How can I write one RegEx for all these possibilities?**

**Issues:**

1. Optional 11th digit,
2. *Moving* hyphen

Comment: Try `^(?:\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{2}|\d{5}-(?:\d{3}-\d{2}|\d{4}-\d{1,2}))$`, see https://regex101.com/r/OXuIC6/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{2}|\d{5}-(?:\d{3}-\d{2}|\d{4}-\d{1,2}))$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OXuIC6/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of the first non-capturing group:

  - `\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{2}` - four digits, `-`, four digits, `-`, two digits
  - `|` - or
  - `\d{5}-` - five digits, `-`
  - `(?:` - start of the second non-capturing group:

    - `\d{3}-\d{2}` - three digits, `-`, two digits
    - `|` - or
    - `\d{4}-\d{1,2}` - four digits, `-` and one or two digits
  - `)` - end of the second non-capturing group
- `)` - end of the first non-capturing group.
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this within pandas DataFrame using lists parsing:

```
# add zeros to each portion of ndc10 to fit 5,4,2 ndc11 0-filled format
a = [f"0{x[0]}" if len(x[0]) == 4 else x[0] for x in list(ndcd.NDC10.str.split("-"))]
b = [f"0{x[1]}" if len(x[1]) == 3 else x[1] for x in list(ndcd.NDC10.str.split("-"))]
c = [f"0{x[2]}" if len(x[2]) == 1 else x[2] for x in list(ndcd.NDC10.str.split("-"))]

# rejoin sections to full ndc11
ndcd["NDC11"] = ["".join(x) for x in list(zip(a, b, c))]
```